# Cohesive block of code

Tags: angularjs, module, typescript, angular

I'm currently reading about modules in angular 2. In Angular documentation there is statement:

"A typical module is a cohesive block of code dedicated to a single purpose."

I want to figure out what they mean by a cohesive block of code?

Can someone explain it simply?

I googled, but I didn't found any good explanation which is simple.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in simple terms you can put it like this - In angular2 the application view is segregated into components. The components have their view and controller. Hence, it enforces better reuse.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now it is actually my component + template which I can export/import when I need to reuse it. In the same way I can export for eg variables, interfaces etc...everything that I can export/import is module in angular 2. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this means something like explained in [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

A class should do one thing and do it well.
A module it similar, just with a bit wider scope.

Cohesive means closely related or belonging together.

Answer (score 0):

**The concept of Cohesion**: means the things that are related should always be part of one unit. They should go together this is called Cohesion.